# How can I change background-style of div with a selection box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, inline-styles

On my current project in React I need to have the possibility to change the background-style (image, width, height etc.) from a 'div' to nine different options.

I've tried it with following code:

```
const styleOptions = [
  {
    backgroundImage: "",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    //backgroundSize: "650px 800px",
    backgroundSize: "cover"
  },
  {
    backgroundImage: "url(/PicturesPattern/Picture1.png)",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    //backgroundSize: "650px 800px",
    backgroundSize: "cover"
  },
  ...//same code for nine Pictures, only diffrent size values
]


class Example extends React.Component {
   state = {
      ...
      ...
      //for selectionField
      isDisabled: false,
      backgroundStyle: styleOptions[0]
   };
   ...
   ...
   ...
   onSelectChange = (event) => { 
      this.setState({
         ...
         currentStyle: styleOptions[event.value + 1]
      });
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <>
            //div for selectionField
            <div className="forBackground" style{this.backgroundStyle}>
            ...
            ...
            //other code
            ...
            ...
         </>
      )
   }
}
```

But on any change from my selection field, there isnt happening anything to the background of the specific div.
When I put "styleOptions[x]" for x every index possible, I get the specific background image and other style options.

What am I doing wrong?
Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the `onSelectChange` function and in the `event.value + 1` part you are adding two different types of variables (string and integer). As a result the background styles of div would not change properly. First, you should write this function as below

```
onSelectChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      backgroundStyle: styleOptions[parseInt(event.target.value) + 1],
    });
  };
```

Then, `style{this.backgroundStyle}` should be changed to `style={this.state.backgroundStyle}`. I also added the height attributes and assigned a `backgroundColor` to make the div and changes more visible

But there were also other minor modifications. So, check the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-brattain-1lrsd?file=/src/App.js) of the corrected version of your code.

Comment: pls let me know if it addresses your problem or it needs more improvements

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I change the option on the state to "backgroundStyle: styleOptions[x] it shows me the background that I put in for 'x'. But when I change it with my selectionField, it still doesnt change my background somehow...

Comment: Just updated the answer, I tried to change the style by clicking the button. I don't know how your real code works but in this simple example you can easily change the background style. Pls check it and tell me if it works for you

Comment: I found my mistake...
When you take a look at the code, the state is called "backgroundStyle" and in the onSelectChange-function, I've typed another name for it, "currentStyle". Totally forgot that I changed the name of it...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Can you mark my answer as the correct answer to your question?